# Magento 2, Dynamic add or refresh block in sale order page

Tags: magento2.2, adminhtml, sales-order, custom-block

Using `Magento 2`, `Sale-Order`, `Block info + history`. How to refresh block in **sale order** page **after summit comment successful**. In image below I need refresh "block comment preview" **after** block comment reload *or* comment has been submitted success.

[image]